# Leer archivo xml y persistir informacion cada cierto tiempo

Tags: java, xml, cron, schedule

Este es el escenario: tengo un archivo xml que contiene información que debe ser almacenada, actualizada o eliminada de mi base de datos cada mes. He tomado dos aproximaciones para leer cada tanto el archivo desde Java:

- Utilicé un cron con `@Scheduled` y la propiedad `cron` para ejecutarla cada 30 días. Acá hago validaciones sobre el nombre del archivo, si tengo el registro de la fecha, no lo vuelvo a leer.
- Utilicé `@EnableBatchProcessing` para ejecutar un proceso cada que se ejecutaba el programa previendo que se despliegue la aplicación cada dos semanas, nuevamente validando si el archivo fue previamente leído.

Sin embargo lo que me están solicitando ahora es que el archivo sea leído cada vez que depositen un nuevo archivo en la carpeta desde donde lo leo y no sé por donde empezar. Existe en Java algo como un "watcher" que este pendiente de esa carpeta y pueda leer ese evento (nuevo archivo depositado en la carpeta)?

Comment: Esto ha sido lo que he encontrado en [so] tal vez te ayude o al menos que te sirva para empezar a hacer algo. [Watching a Directory for Changes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452527/watching-a-directory-for-changes-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes implementar [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) que te permite detectar cuando se ha creado un archivo,eliminado o modificado. También utilizado  [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) puedes programar tareas a tu gusto. De esta manera utilizando WatchService puedes lanzar un job(quartz) para que te haga alguna tarea.

Espero que te haya ayudado.